# Renaming multi-index column after reading an HTML page

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a table from this [webpage](https://www.nratrafficdata.ie/c2/tfhourdirection.asp?sgid=ZvyVmXU8jBt9PJE$c7UXt6&spid=NRA_000000001081&reportdate=2018-12-01&enddate=2018-12-01), which contains multiple Html tables, after successfully reading them , i want to renmae them. I have tried many options but i doesn't work plus the response is multindexed and tried almost everything like df.rename etc.
I am adding the code and response below, can somebody help ?

Code:

````
import uuid
import pandas as pd

class traffic():
   def __init__(self):
       ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
       global homePage
       global downloadDir
       global filname
       pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
       pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
       pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
       downloadDir = "C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\digitalOcean\\venv\\testDara\\"
       uFileName = str(uuid.uuid4())
       filname = downloadDir + uFileName + ".csv"
       dailyUrl = "https://www.nratrafficdata.ie/c2/tfhourdirection.asp?sgid=ZvyVmXU8jBt9PJE$c7UXt6&spid=NRA_000000001081&reportdate=2018-12-01&enddate=2018-12-01"
       iDf = pd.read_html(dailyUrl, index_col=False)
       df = iDf[0]
       #dff = df.rename({'1':'one', '2':'two'}, axis='columns', inplace=True)
       print(df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   objCall = traffic()```

Example response:

check this [1]: https://pasteboard.co/HXPrTVw.png "response"
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it using this, `df.columns = ['ccc','dd','cccs','dd','ddd', 'dddd']`